# DatePicker onError function being called on passing valid date

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/onerror-lp8vb)

When I enter date as `2020-01-01` the `onError` function gets fired with `reason=null`.

This happens for all days from 01 to 09.

For dates starting from `2021-01-10` onwards `onError` doesn't fire.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

I am using -

`@material-ui/core": "^5.0.0-beta.5`
`@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.44`